# Relaxing unescaped HTML filtering inside <pre> tags?

Tags: comments

By default, WordPress strips out any content that might be unescaped HTML in comments from unregistered users, which is good to protect against XSS, but it unnecessarily extends that filtering into `<pre>` elements too.  On my blog, where almost every post generates comments that benefit from HTML code snippets, that filtering has caused my users (and myself) lots of frustrating trouble.

Is there a way to "fix" that overly aggressive filtering inside `<pre>` elements within unregistered comments, without disabling it for the rest of the comment?  Preferably, in a way that survives upgrades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a small solution; the highlighting was in my blog via javascript

```
function pre_esc_html($content) {
  return preg_replace_callback(
    '#(<pre.*?>)(.*?)(</pre>)#imsu',
    create_function(
      '$i',
      'return $i[1].esc_html($i[2]).$i[3];'
    ),
    $content
  );
}

add_filter(
  'the_content',
  'pre_esc_html',
  9
);
```

Comment: There's a space in the closing `pre` tag that will prevent this from working.

Comment: i have add the prioritiy to 9 on the hook to the_content; this is important for nice format. Now comes the function before wpautop() and now is the code in the same design how in your IDE or editor. Without the priority 0 fomrat wpautop on all html-tags to a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Although this might be a little more than you're looking for, [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) disables HTML filtering within `<pre>` tags inside posts and comments (AFAIK). It also works for Wordpress 3.0, even though the website says it works only with 2.8.

If you're looking to make it simpler, I suggest looking in `wp-syntax.php` within the plugin (specifically at the very bottom where they use `add_filters()` to see how they disable Wordpress's automatic HTML filtering within `<pre>` tags. You can then apply that to comments.

EDIT: I have looked at the file, and they use regex and PHP's [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to preserve the original HTML within `<pre>` tags. You might have to modify it to fit your needs.

You would have, for example (note: untested code):

```
<?php
// Unique string for placeholder
$custom_token = md5(uniqid(rand()));

// Store all the matches in an array
$custom_matches = array();

function custom_substitute(&$match) {
    global $custom_token, $custom_matches;

    $i = count($custom_matches);

    // Store the match for later use
    $custom_matches[$i] = $match;

    // Unique placeholder so that we know where to put the code that was ripped out
    return '<p>' . $custom_token . '</p>';
}

function custom_replace($match) {
    global $custom_matches;

    $i = intval($match[1]);
    $match = $custom_matches[$i];

    // The index might be off - you might want to double-check it
    return htmlentities($match[1]);
}

function custom_before_content_filter($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\s*<pre+>(.*)<\/pre>\s*/siU", 'custom_substitute', $content);
}

function custom_after_content_filter($content) {
    global $custom_token;

    return preg_replace_callback("/<p>\s*" . $custom_token . "\s*<\/p>/si", 'custom_replace', $content);
}
// Run the "before" filter first, with priority of 0
add_filter('comment_text', 'custom_before_content_filter', 0);

// Now run the "after" filter
add_filter('comment_text', 'custom_after_content_filter', 99);
```

Comment: WP-Syntax is what I'm using now.  It *does* allow anonymous users to format their code in comments, but it doesn't take precedence over WordPress' HTML filtering.  So, if they include any HTML (or anything that looks like HTML, like PHP, ASP, etc), that gets stripped out before the formatting.